# CodeDeploy Fails but files make it to EC2 Instance in the wrong place

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy, aws-codecommit

I set up CodeCommit -> CodePipeline -> CodeDeploy and the deploy fails, but the files I commited to CodeCommit show up in

`/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/b20baedc-1ba0-408e-b74c-8615b3d87f74/d-AN5IXPSZJ/deployment-archive`

This is the error message I get when the deployment fails:

`Deployment Failed
The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems. (Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS)`

I would like the files to be put into `/src/website/website-name`

Answer (score 0):

CodeDeploy uses an appspec.yml file to define where the deployment should end up.

If you look at this [AppSpec File Example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/app-spec-ref-example.html) you'll see how source and destination is defined. Check that your `destination:` correctly points to `/src/website/website-name`.

Answer (score 0):

The deployment failed might be caused by different problems. Could you go to the CodeDeploy console, choose the deployment tab at top left(below aws bar), find the deploymentId, and then click the deploymentId, you'll able to see the deployment details and each instances status. If there is any instance has status Failed, you can check the lifecycle event status of that instance, and error log.